# Run application on another mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake

I have created a very simple Hello World application in Xcode, C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,  char * argv[])
{
   cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

The Xcode project was created with Cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set (CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)


PROJECT ( Prueba )

SET ( GedcomToHtml_SRCS         
    main.cpp
)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} )


#enable all warnings
ADD_DEFINITIONS ( -Wall )

#Here we instruct to build sample executable from all the source files
ADD_EXECUTABLE ( Prueba ${GedcomToHtml_SRCS} 
)

#last thing that we need to do is to tell CMake what libraries our executable needs
#Luckily FIND_PACKAGE preparted QT_LIBRARIES variable for us
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( Prueba )
```

When I compile it, a terminal application is created in the Debug folder. I have sent this application to another computer and tried to run it, but the other computer responds with Segmentation fault.

The OS of the original mac is 10.8.2, and the OS of the target mac is 10.6.8.

How can I run an application created in my original mac, in the target mac?
Thanks

Comment: Can you throw a debugger at it on the other mac to find our where it's segfaulting?

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to install Xcode on the other computer. Is there another way to debug it without installing anything on the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was add this line to my CMakeLists.txt file:

SET(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should instruct the compiler what the earliest Mac OS X version is on which the program will run. To do this you can use `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6` in your case given it should also run on 10.6.8. And additionally you should set the root directory for headers using the `-isysroot <10.6 SDK directory>` flag.

So in CMake this would amount to the following:

```
SET(SDK "10.6")
SET(DEV_SDK "/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX${SDK}.sdk")

ADD_DEFINITIONS(
  -isysroot ${DEV_SDK} 
  -mmacosx-version-min=${SDK}
  )

SET(
  CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -isysroot ${DEV_SDK} -mmacosx-version-min=${SDK}"
  )
SET(
  CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
  "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -isysroot ${DEV_SDK} -mmacosx-version-min=${SDK}"
  )
SET(
  CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS
  "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS} -isysroot ${DEV_SDK} -mmacosx-version-min=${SDK}"
  )
```

Note that your SDK might be located somewhere else so substitute the correct directory.

Comment: I can't find the SDK. Do you know how I can find its location?

Comment: Ok, I found it using "sudo find / -name *.sdk -print" on the terminal. But now, when I compile it says iostream not found. I think its because I dont have MacOSX.6.sdk. Is there a way I can download it?